# can't suppress the function name to be displayed when using nested ipywidgets interact functions

Tags: python, ipywidgets

Using nested widgets interact functions, as shown in minimun case example below, however can't suppress the function name to be displayed. Semi-colon does not work.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

def dummy_func(a, b):
    return a + b

def interactive_dummy_func(b=4, a=2):
    return widgets.interact(dummy_func, 
                             a = a,
                             b = b);

@widgets.interact
def wrapped_interactive_dummy_func(condition=True):
    if condition == True:
        return interactive_dummy_func(a=3, b=5);
    else:
        return "Something else"
```

Output always show the function name and can't manage to suppress it

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interact wrapped function automatically displays, so no need to return anything in your last function (that is where the function name is coming from)

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets

def dummy_func(a, b):
    return a + b

def interactive_dummy_func(b=4, a=2):
    return widgets.interact(dummy_func, 
                             a = a,
                             b = b)

@widgets.interact
def wrapped_interactive_dummy_func(condition=True):
    if condition == True:
        interactive_dummy_func(a=3, b=5)
    else:
        return "Something else"
```